# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkoutLineItemsAdd' of undefined in shopify-buy library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, shopify, shopify-template

I'm using [The Shopify Buy plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-buy) in my **react-native** application for guest checkout

But I'm facing the issue (see the image below)

[image: issue]

I also refered https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk/issues/518 for solution but I dont have this type of problem in my code.

Please any help is appreciated.

**My Code**

```
import Client from 'shopify-buy';

const client = Client.buildClient({
    storefrontAccessToken: my_token,
    domain: my_domain
});
export default class App extends Component {
   componentWillMount() {
      client.checkout.create().then((res) => {
         this.setState({
            checkout: res,
         });
      });
  }
  _handleAddToBagBtn = (variantID) => {  
      const checkoutId = this.state.checkout.id;  
      const lineItemsToAdd = [{'variantID': variantID, quantity: 1}];  
      client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd).then((checkout) => { 
        console.warn(checkout.lineItems);  
     });  
  }
}
render() {
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._handleAddToBagBtn(variantID)} >Click Here</TouchableOpacity>
   );
}
```

Comment: What is `client` in here? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: please have a look in my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem today using the Storefont API, but solved it as follows.

Instead of using the `variantId` numeric value directly, you need to use a Base64 encoded string of the `graphql_api_id` property which is associated with the variant.

Unencoded, these look like this: `gid://shopify/ProductVariant/12434084921391`. You can get these from product objects, but you can also create them directly from your numeric `variantId`.

In your code, change this function:

```
_handleAddToBagBtn = (variantId) => {  
  const checkoutId = this.state.checkout.id;
  const lineItemsToAdd = [{
    variantId: window.btoa(`gid://shopify/ProductVariant/${variantId}`),
    quantity: 1
  }];  
  client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd).then((checkout) = { 
    console.warn(checkout.lineItems);  
 });
```

}

Note I also changed `variantID` to `variantId` as this is the identifier used by Shopify, not `variantID`.

In my case, this got rid of the error and returned a GraphQL model. Hope that helps.

Comment: +1. Thank you for this answer! The official documentation for the Shopify JavaScript Buy SDK is very incomplete and often wrong. After a day of trying to go by the docs and failing miserably I found this and it worked.

Comment: Delighted it helped you @Azer - best of luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

What seems to me is that `Client.buildClient()` is returning a promise. You should do something like this:

```
const client = Client.buildClient({
    storefrontAccessToken: my_token,
    domain: my_domain
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

You can check if you are getting a valid response or an error and go ahead accordingly.

Comment: I write this code but I'm getting below error:  `undefined is not a function(near'...}).then(function(res){...')`

Comment: What do you get if you console log `client.checkout` inside `handleAddToBagBtn`? Or you can also use `debugger` in the first line of the function.

Comment: I found this: `{"graphQLClient":{"typeBundle":{"types":{"QueryRoot":{"name":"QueryRoot","kind":"OBJECT","fieldBaseTypes":{"node":"Node","nodes":"Node","shop":"Shop"}.........` inshort graphQLClient object

Comment: Replace `const lineItemsToAdd = [{'variantID': variantID, quantity: 1}];` with `const lineItemsToAdd = [{'variantId': variantID, quantity: 1}];` Most probably the problem is with the variantID. Check if your are getting the correct Id and passing it correctly. And also the key.

Comment: yes I tried that spell too.. but it gives me same warning